# ID Number Wasn't Displayed At The Page Address

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to update my database using php but the problem is I think the ID wasn't being called. It appears to be `http://localhost/FolderName/update.php?id=$twothree[id]` when it should be `http://localhost/FolderName/update.php?id=1` (or some id # from the db)

I am trying to call the ID Number using this code below.

```
<?php while($twothree=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['ssh']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['provi']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['muni']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['impact']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['advice']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['typhoon']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['warning']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $twothree['date']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href='edit.php?id=$twothree[id]'> Edit </a>
            <a href='#'> Delete </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope you guys can tell what I've been doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, i think you should change `<a href='edit.php?id=$twothree[id]'> Edit </a>` to `<a href='edit.php?id=<?=$twothree[id];?>'> Edit </a>`

Answer (score 4):

You need to print your variable `$twothree[id]` on the HTML.

As it is, your PHP variable `$twothree[id]` is being treated as HTML text.

So: `<a href='edit.php?id=<?php echo $twothree[id]; ?>'> Edit </a>`